# return an int or pass an int pointer -- whats better?

Tags: c

which of these two is better?

```
void SetBit(int *flag, int bit)
{
    *flag |= 1 << bit;
}
```

Or

```
int SetBit(int flag, int bit)
{
    flag |= 1 << bit;
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I feel it's best to use the entire int (or char or short or whatever) as the boolean flag. Sure it uses more memory but it's much more readable. Unless memory is a serious restriction, avoid bit-hacks when you can.

Comment: @Polaris: My guess would be that people were thinking it was a performance question (I almost downvoted for that reason before rereading it a few times...)

Comment: @emge For something so trivial, why do you want to code a separate function? Too many unneeded calls are always a performance hazard.

Comment: @Arpan: Because any reasonable compiler nowadays is going to inline the call to this anyway, and it makes the code more readable.

Comment: @Billy Agreed. But it's probably not a good practice to have expectations out of compilers -- the relationship (between developers and compilers) is rather slippery.

Comment: @Arpan: 2 reasons, it's makes the code more readable and it is also less error prone to typos...

    flag = SetBit(flag, A_FLAG);

as opposed to 
    flag |= 1 << A_FLAG; (if you forget any of |, =, or one of <) it will compile and cause some serious problems...

Comment: @emge a `#define` then couldn't be more suitable?

Comment: `flag |= 1<<A_FLAG` is perfectly readable. By the way, a better way to do this would be to define `A_POS` and then `#define A_FLAG (1<<A_POS)`. Then your code can just use `flag |= A_FLAG`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like the second one because it doesn't have any side effects.  If you want to modify `flag`, you can simply assign the result to itself:

```
flag = SetBit(flag, 4);
```

Answer (score 6):

Neither.

```
int SetBit(int flag, int bit)
{
    return flag | 1 << bit;
}
```

Comment: Definitely this. Don't dig in a parameter variable if you don't have a really good reason to. Return modified value and let the user assign it back into the variable if they like.

Comment: You don't think the compiler would maybe optimize that away anyway?

Comment: @Platinum: It's not a performance thing, it's a readability thing.

Comment: @Platinum: It's not that it's unreadable. It's that this one is more readable. With this version it's immediately clear that `flag` is not being modified. The original version has me looking up at the argument list to ensure `flag` is not a reference variable. (C doesn't have them, but C++ does, and so do most other languages)

Comment: subjective. I would prefer this just because it is more compact, but still subjective, and only-C-programmers have not to check if it is ref or not (the Q is tagged C); reading a source in Lang-X should create a context in mind to interpret Lang-X, not Lang-Y or most other languages; so that hardly we can be confused if we are in the C-context.

Comment: @Shin: Most of us know more than, and are experienced with more than, one language.

Comment: @Billy one more reason to get no confusion about flag being or not a reference variable in C

Answer (score 5):

It depends.

first one is imperative style, second one is functional style.

If you want to do

```
SetBit(SetBit(... SetBit(flag, b1), b2),...), bn)
```

do the second one.
If you want

```
SetBit(&flag, b1)
SetBit(&flag, b2)
...
SetBit(&flag, bn)
```

do the first one. In C, I would prefer the latter (ie. the imperative one). In other languages/contexts, the former may be a good idea.

Comment: A poor use of the functional style (deeply nesting functions) is not an excuse to avoid it. If you want to list them all out on separate lines you can just assign the result of SetBit to the flag variable on each line.

Comment: Would you seriously actually recommend using that first pattern in C, ever? (No downvote, but I have to question your mentioning it all because that will be nearly unreadable!)

Comment: @Platinum I wouldn't for sure, but I couldn't think of a good and immediate justification for the functional construct here.

Comment: Really, if you're doing SetBit on the same value a bunch of times in a row, I think it's probably a bit daft not to go with 'flag |= 0xDEADBEEF' or whatevet the bit pattern you want is. I would actually find that easier to read, and of course faster too. Unless you're using FD_SET for select() or something. Or: 'flag |= (FLAG_A | FLAG_B | ...)' if ypu have approproate constants representing the bits to set.

Comment: Functional style: 'reduce SetBit flag [b1, b2, ...]' :-)

Comment: @Owen: yep, but hard to do properly in C :(

Answer (score 5):

I would use a macro:

```
#define BIT_SET(a, bit) ((a) | (1 << (bit)))
```

Comment: Why not, but I'd still name it SET_BIT ;)

Comment: +1 definitely a macro (a function call is expensive in such cases)

Comment: a classical usage of macros, I would say... +1 me too

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, I think this just encourages people to use "magic numbers" as flags:

```
SetBit(&flags, 12); // 12 is the flag for Super mode
```

What you actually want is named constants:

```
#define SUPERMODE_FLAG 12
...
SetBit(&flags, SUPERMODE_FLAG);
```

But if you're going to use named constants, you might as well name masks rather than bit numbers, in which case the operation is so simple there's no need for a helper function:

```
#define SUPERMODE_MASK (1 << 12)
....
flags |= SUPERMODE_MASK;
```

In the unusual case that you're manipulating individual bits by number, without knowing what they mean, then I prefer the second for the same reason as Kristo - I find side-effect-free functions slightly easier to reason about than mutators.

Answer (score 1):

I like the second one better...

However, I'd recommend changing the name of your function to be more descriptive (assuming this is the actual name).  "SetBit" doesn't do much to describe what the function does or returns :)

Comment: It doesn't? It seems to make sense to me -- it sets the bit in the given flag variable.

Comment: Actually I disagree - the function sets a bit. The function could be used in any context where a bit must be set.

Comment: @Polaris: The one specified by the "bit" argument.

Comment: @Polaris: what would you call the function? I thought the name was clear and simple, all the function does is set the bit in the flag.

Comment: Does it set the bit to a 1 or a 0?

Comment: @Polaris: It sets the bit. Setting a bit is assigning 1 to it. To reverse the process and set it to 0 is called resetting the bit.

Comment: I guess I'm just used to "set" being very generic from all the .NET I've been doing lately.

Comment: he pointed an interesting aspect anyway as side effect of the speech: SetBit lets me think it sets the bit, not that it returns it; so I would expect a "syntax" like `SetBit(a, bit)` and not `a = SetBit(a, bit)`; conventional anyway, since people gets fastly used to the assigned meaning that they can see in th way the func/macro is used. -- Often `set` means set to 1, and `clear` means `set to 0`, only convention widely used when handling bits.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

In that case, either way would really work. But I can think of two special cases where I would favor using a pointer.

1. If the type you're passing in is large and a value copy would be expensive, use a pointer for performance reasons.
2. If you need to return something else, maybe a status code or success/failure indication, then you need to use the pointer so that you can leave room to return the value you need to return.

I personally think that outside of those situations, the second one (pass/return by value) is clearer and slightly more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The second is better because it won't crash.

The first one <strike>will</strike> could crash if you pass in an <strike>NULL</strike> invalid pointer so you'd need to have some code to check and handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an `int` to save time dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: This function is going to be inlined by any reasonable compiler anyway -- I'd not worry about performance here.

Comment: Especially in the embedded systems world, not all compilers will inline such things.  Further, the <i>pattern</i> arises in many cases where the code is sufficiently complex that inlining it would be impractical.  By my interpretation, the question was not about how he should set bits in a variable, but about which pattern of coding was better.

Answer (score 0):

First is OK if functions is going to be inlined. Without inlining that's bit too much overhead to pass around pointers to ints. (On 64bit LP64 archs, int is 4 bytes, pointer is 8.)

Second ... function name SetBit() is going to cause some mild confusion. Name implies that function changes something while in fact it doesn't. As long as you are OK with the name, then it is performance-wise a better option.

E.g. Linux kernel uses for many similar things the pointer variant, since often memory location of the datum is important or required for portability. But they either make all such functions a preprocessor macro or mark with gcc's always_inline attribute. For user-land, plain application programming, I'd say the second should be preferred. Only pick a better name.

Answer (score 0):

If the only pattern for using the function will be "variable = doSomething(variable);" and performance is not an issue, I would consider "doSomething(&variable);" to be more legible.  The only time I would favor the former would be if the destination was sometimes something other than the source, or if performance were crucial and one's compiler could not efficiently handle the latter case (common on embedded systems).

It should be noted that the latter format allows something the former does not.  In VB-style:

```
Sub OrBits(ByRef N as Integer, ByVal Bits as Integer)
  Dim OldValue as Integer
  Do
    OldValue = N
  Loop While Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(N, OldValue or Bits,  OldValue) <> OldValue
End Sub
```

The effect of this code will always be to OR the specified bits into N, even if something else changes N while the function is running.  It is not possible to achieve such behavior with the read-and-return strategy.